# Dificuldade para implementação de paginação no Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Vocês podem perceber que paginação feita pelo back-end está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objetivo é conseguir retorna os três primeiros registros da primeira aba no Angular como mostra no Postman, se eu conseguir concluir essa primeira etapa da implementação vou poder fazer o resto.

Essa foi minha tentativa;

Classe de serviço;

```
  getMenuPage(skip, limit): Observable<any>{
      return this._http.get(`${this.url}/menuspage?page=${skip}&size=${limit}`)
      .map(res => res.json());

    }
```

E esse é minha classe de componente;

```
  public title: string;
  public menu: Menu[];

  constructor(
    private _menuService: MenuAdminService
  ) {
      this.title = 'Lista de Cardápios';

    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMenusPage(0,4);
  }

  getMenusPage(skip, limit) {
    this._menuService.getMenuPage(skip, limit).subscribe(
      response => {
       console.log(response.data)
        if (!response.data) {

        } else {
          this.menu = response.data;
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

O retorno do meu consoles do navegador é esse:

```
Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

Como faço para corrigir essa implementação?

Comment: parece que tem um typo na sua url tenta: `${this.url}/menuspage?skip=${skip}&limit=${limit}`

Comment: Foi isso mesmo @EduardoVargas, muito obrigado

Comment: Pode colocar sua resposta, muito obrigado.